# Play Framework 2.3.4 - How to call Results.badRequest() on a POST request and direct to method in controller not mapped by routes?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.3

Ok my title is a bit difficult to understand.

What I am trying to achieve is the following.

My controller:

```
public static Result addSomething() {
    return getSomething(SOME_FORM);
}

public static Result addSomething(Form<SomeFormDetails> someForm) {
    // Do complicated stuff to get someObject and someOtherObject
    return ok(com.me.views.html.pages.AddSomething
            .render(someObject, someOtherObject, someForm));
}

public static Result postFromSomeForm() {
    Form<SomeFormDetails> filledForm = SOME_FORM.bindFromRequest();
    SomeFormDetails details = filledForm.get();
    // do some checks
    if (Database.addStuff(details)) {
        return redirect(com.me.controllers.routes.Get.index());
    } else {
        // #### THIS IS THE IMPORTANT BIT ####
        // this next line is not possible as I do not have the
        // method addSomething(Form<SomeFormDetails> someForm) mapped
        // in routes, but you get what I mean
        return badRequest(com.me.controllers.routes.Get.addSomething
                .render(filledForm));
        // #### THIS IS THE IMPORTANT BIT ####
    }
}
```

routes

```
GET     /something             com.me.controllers.Get.addSomething()
POST    /something/add         com.me.controllers.Get.postFromSomeForm()
```

What I want to avoid doing is having lots of unnecessary code repeated to get the `someObject` and `someOtherObject` objects under the `postFromSomeForm()` method.

I am aware that I can move the bit denoted by `// Do complicated stuff to get someObject and someOtherObject` into another method, but due to the nature of the two objects it is not simple.

I could add the `addSomething(Form<SomeFormDetails> someForm)` to the routes, if I rename (overloaded methods don't seem to be allowed), but this is not desirable as it would cause lots of other problems.

I cannot simply change the important bit to:

```
return badRequest(com.me.controllers.Get.addSomething.render(filledForm));
```

as this is not supported (ie without the using the reverseGet). FYI it gives `The method badRequest(Content) in the type Results is not applicable for the arguments (Result)`.

I'm pretty sure that I am trying to achieve something easy but there doesn't sem to be an easy way to achieve it in using this framework because of all the reverseGet bits generated from the routes not having same return types as the controller methods (which I know is of course the case and understand that it is required)

Can anyone let me know if there is a simple supported way to achieve what I am trying to achieve? Please let me know if the question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want just making that action return the rendered template instead of a result:

```
public static String addSomething(Form<SomeFormDetails> someForm) {
    // Do complicated stuff to get someObject and someOtherObject
    return com.me.views.html.pages.AddSomething
            .render(someObject, someOtherObject, someForm).body();
}

// latter
return badRequest(com.me.controllers.routes.Get.addSomething.render(filledForm));
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how this solves the problem, could you please elaborate? I still need to return a type `Result` from `addSomething()`.

Comment: Why do you need it to return a result if it is not used in your routes? Also please explain the part "I am aware that I can move (...) into another method, but due to the nature of the two objects it is not simple." It is because of accessing request object/parameters?

Comment: The method `addSomething()` is mapped (and needs to return `Result`) but the method `addSomething(Form<SomeFormDetails> someForm)` is not mapped but is called from the first, I can't simply change the method as you describe as it would break `addSomething()`

Comment: The bit you ask me to explain more is not really explainable as this is really a generic question, I simply do not want to move that code into a different method. I'm trying to understand how to send a 400_BAD_REQUEST but use an existing controller but I think this is not possible as I want to call a method that returns a 200_OK from a method that should return a 400_BAD_REQUEST, I think simply I need to think more about the logic I am trying to achieve. Basically I wanted the convenience of calling something like it existed in routes without is actually being in routes.